# Pushing source files to bitbucket in visual studio

Tags: c++, git, bitbucket, push

I would like to know how to push .cpp files and .h files in visual studio 2017. whenever I do a commit i push the solution and everything in the build folder. I just want to be able to push .cpp files and header files whenever i edit them. Im using windows 10 but I do recall on linux, using vim, the task was simpler, because i used the command line.

Comment: You can add a `.gitignore` file

Comment: i dont mind the build folder, which contains the .sln to be pushed. I'm just wondering how do  i include the source folder that includes the .cpp and header files?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.gitignore` to your root of this solution with following contents:

```
build
```

This should ignore all the files and folders within you `build` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do is just to learn the command line syntax on windows with Git bash. Most online help is given with the command line syntax in mind.